# Android eclipse: exporting apk

Tags: android, eclipse, export, apk

I've problem with exporting apk from eclipse: after I export project (even unsigned, not using keystore), if I rename .apk to .zip and open, it only contains "classes.dex", not anything else. It also weighs only 26 kb, while debug apk weighs 2.6 mb.

Problem persists even on simpliest projects (like one activity with one button). On exporting process it shows no errors.

My system is Windows 7, tried using Indigo and Juno eclipse. Tried installing new android sdk and reinstalling eclipse, tried to "Clean" projects and to configure build. No changes.

Thanks in advance.

Update:
I've just created new "Hello World" project, with auto-generated Manifest:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.testproject"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="7"
    android:targetSdkVersion="7" />

<application
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_main" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

which works perfectly when I click "Run" button, but when I export it and try to install with adb, I get "file 'C:...\TestProject.apk' does not contain AndroidManifest.xml"

Comment: Is there any reason for changing the name to .zip?

Comment: What does the manifest in the project look like?

Comment: the reason is that I cant install it, manifest not found error -- as I renamed it and openet, theres no manifest inside.
manifest is basically standard, because its same error on every of my project, even simpliest ones.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved my problem by installing ubuntu, exporting worked perfectly there.

Comment: I suggest looking into the issue a bit more since having to install ubuntu really shouldnt be needed.  I develop on several windows boxes and linux boxes and none have this problem.

Comment: I guess the problem was with my windows, had few other issues and had to reinstall it afterall

Answer (score 1):

.apk is just a file for installing your app. .dex files and resources is all what is necessary for this. You can read more about building android app [here](http://developer.android.com/tools/building/index.html). The size is reduced as a result of compressing class files into dex and using [proguard](http://proguard.sourceforge.net/)

Comment: thanks for quick answer and the link, but the exported apk is supposed to have manifest file and resources, isnt it? because this 26 kb apk of mine doesnt have right icon (while debug apk does), and if I try to install it, it says that AndroidManifest not found.